# Print to console which screen I'm on with the Stack.Navigator component react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Is there a way to put a `console.log` on each screen to know which screen we are on, through the Stack.Navigator component? I'm using React Native and TypeScript.

I don't want to manually add a `console.log` on each screen because I have so many.

I have in mind to use something like this:

```
  <Stack.Navigator screenListeners={{state: (e) => { console.log(...) }}} />
```

thanks...

Comment: Take a look on this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking

Answer (score 0):

```
import  React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  useEffect=()=>{
    console.log("HomeScreen")
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen() {
   useEffect=()=>{
    console.log("DetalisScreen")
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**I think this will help you!!**

learn more about useEffect [click here](https://www.reactnative.express/react/hooks/useeffect)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).